# Is there a WCF service request queue performance counter?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, performancecounter, perfmon

There is a nice ASP.NET perf counter category and set of counters that can be used to track the request queue during perf test runs. However I can't find similar set for a WCF service **not** hosted thru IIS. Our WCF services are run as Windows services using net-tcp protocols. I've learned that there are a couple binding parameters that control queuing (`Binding.MaxConnections` and `Binding.ListenBacklog`). It wasn't a very easy find. So I wonder going forward, is there a why to track these two values in PerfMon?

Answer (score 6):

Under the **ServiceModelService** performance counter category you can find the following set of queue performance counters:

- Queue Dropped Messages
- Queue Dropped Messages Per Second
- Queued Poison Messages
- Queued Poison Messages Per Second
- Queued Rejected Messages
- Queued Rejected Messages Per Second

None of which provide the information you're looking for. The performance counter that I could find more closely related to what you want is:

- Percent of Max Concurrent Calls

Which provides the number of concurrent calls as a percent of maximum concurrent calls.

To see a complete list of available WCF performance counters [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx).